# Unnest and concatenate values in r

Tags: r, concatenation

I am trying to unnest two columns that do not always have the same number of values per cell and then concatenate the values that have a correspond between the two columns. For example:

```
library('dplyr')
library('tidyr')

#Sample Data
df <- data.frame(id = c(1:4),
             first.names = c('Michael, Jim', 'Michael, Michael', 'Creed', 'Creed, Jim'),
             last.names = c('Scott, Halpert', 'Scott, Cera', '', 'Halpert'))
```

Not all values in df$first.names are associated with a value in df$last.names. I am trying to get the following results:

```
#Desired output
df.results <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,4),
                     first.names = c('Michael', 'Jim', 'Michael', 'Michael', 'Creed', 'Creed', 'Jim'),
                     last.names = c('Scott', 'Halpert', 'Scott', 'Cera', '', '', 'Halpert'),
                     full.names = c('Michael Scott', 'Jim Halpert', 'Michael Scott', 'Michael Cera', 'Creed', 'Creed', 'Jim Halpert'))
```

I have tried using unnest, it works for first.names, but not for last.names (it drops the row where last.names is blank):

```
#convert to characters
df$first.names <- as.character(df$first.names)
df$last.names <- as.character(df$last.names)

#Unnest first names
df <- df %>% 
      transform(first.names = strsplit(first.names, ',')) %>%
      unnest(first.names)%>%
      transform(last.names = strsplit(last.names, ',')) %>%
      unnest(last.names)
```

I was then going to delete duplicate lines, but that still does not solve the the issues with the values in df$first.names that do not have a value in df$last.names

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: One issue in your data is the last row 'last.names` have only single entry.  How do you decide it should go with 'Creed' or 'Jim' from 'first.names'.  Is that based on earlier entry of 'Jim'.  But that could lead to issues when there are people with the same last names

Comment: that is an issue i am facing, currently, I know that only certain first names have no last name. i was thinking maybe a dictionary would help, but that is more of my python background... I am trying to run your code, been having trouble getting the tidyverse package installed

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate_at(2:3, ~ strsplit(as.character(.x), ',') %>% map(~ str_trim(.x))) %>%
  mutate(
    First = map2_chr(first.names, last.names, ~ paste(.x[1], .y[1])),
    Second = map2_chr(first.names, last.names, ~ paste(.x[2], .y[2]))
  ) %>%
  mutate_at(4:5, ~ str_remove_all(.x, 'NA') %>% str_trim()) %>%
  gather('x', 'full.names', First:Second) %>%
  filter(full.names != '') %>%
  mutate(
    first.names = map_chr(full.names, ~ str_split(.x, ' ')[[1]][1]),
    last.names = map_chr(full.names, ~ str_split(.x, ' ')[[1]][2]) %>%
      replace_na('')
  ) %>%
  select(-x) %>%
  arrange(id)
```

I can include a logic, that if there is one `last.names` it will combine it with the second `first.names` to get the same result, but I don't think this is what you want. Vector with `first.names` that has no `second.names` can solve the problem.

Comment: Chabros your solution is very close, it runs into a similar problem I have faced. Lines 6 and 7 of the final output are incorrect. firstname 'Creed' will never have a last.name, and first.name 'Jim' should always get associated with last.name 'Halpert'